# Changing the title of a popular question

Tags: discussion, edits, title

I changed the title of [this popular question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7517588/238886) from:

```
Is this an g++ optimization bug?
```

to:

```
Different floating point result with optimization enabled - compiler bug?
```

but I am having second thoughts.  It is considered good practice to edit a title to better reflect the question, with the goal of producing better search results for those who have the same problem.  However, I wonder if the popularity of a question is evidence that its title is working well.  Should one be reluctant to change the title of a popular question?

Comment: Personally, I think it is a better title that will help people find it through search.  Its popularity may be in part that it is part of the [tag:c++-faq].

Comment: I also think that's a better title. Though, in terms of popularity, it only has 3k views. Not sure if that is very popular for a 2+ year old question.

Comment: @JoshC, good point.  My idea of "popular" has apparently been biased by my working in a bit of a niche environment--Ruby questions.  A Ruby question with a score of 80 would be quite popular, relative to other Ruby questions.